# PHP Symfony email form validation after @

Tags: php, validation, symfony, email

With my form builder I have an email field set up like this:

```
       ->add('email', 'email', (array(
            'label'              => 'correo electrónico',
            'translation_domain' => 'SonataUserBundle',
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'correo electrónico',
            ),
        )))
```

So lets say a user enters his value in the email field:

```
test - I get message to include @. Everything is fine here
test@ - it asks me to enter the following part of @. Everything is fine
test@ttt - he thinks this is a valid email and creates a user.
```

Instead it should give an error of an invalid email.. It should only accept atleast with .com or something... Is it possible to do in formbuilder?
I want to make this in less code, js, as possible..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EmailType field is a text field that is rendered using the HTML5  tag. So it is validated by a browser only. You should validate this field using [Email Validation Constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Email.html)